# Solution for Linq2SQL expressions that has no translation

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

Is there a way to provide translation for expressions that have no translation ?

like double.parse()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option (with LINQ-to-SQL at least) is to write the functionality you are missing as a [UDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214363(SQL.80).aspx) and add it to the data-context; then you can use `ctx.MyMethod(cust.SomeValue)` etc in your LINQ query. Note that this may have performance implications if you are wanting it to run it for every row in the table. Essentially your TSQL will involve `user.MyUdf(table.SomeValue)`, etc.